# Retrieve PostgreSQL column using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to return certain columns from a table in a database but I have an issue with one specific column.

```
import sqlalchemy as db

engine = db.create_engine('postgresql://username:password@host:port/db')
table_a = db.Table("table_a", db.MetaData(), autoload = True, autoload_with = engine)

query = db.select([table_a.columns.document_num.distinct(),
                   table_a.columns.class])
```

As you can see from the scrip above, one of the columns is named `class` which generates an invalid syntax error.

Renaming the column in the database is, unfortunately, not an option so I am trying to find another way around this.

Comment: `table_a.columns["class"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
getattr(table_a.columns, "class")
```

to get a column by name. This will also work if "class" is a variable for example

```
class = "class"
getattr(table_a.columns, class)
```